# Preserve GCP's after gdalwarp

Tags: gdal, georeferencing, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

I'm trying to figure out how I can preserve my GCP's after a gdalwarp. I need the georeferenced GCP's data, so I can calculate the Root Mean Squared Error.

Is there a way to preserve this data, and somehow use it, or are there other ways to calculate the RMSE of a georeferenced raster file?

Comment: Have you tried saving the warping result as .vrt? This should give you an editable file.

Comment: I'm currently warping to a GTiff, I'll give the .vrt a try!

Comment: You could warp to both formats in a batch if you prefer to work on with a Geotif.

Comment: You can't have GCPs in warped images. It is either or, see http://gdal.org/1.11/gdal_datamodel.html "GDAL datasets have two ways of describing the relationship between raster positions (in pixel/line coordinates) and georeferenced coordinates. The first, and most commonly used is the affine transform (the other is GCPs)."  Save your GCPs into text file for future needs for example with listgeo.

Comment: You should not really calculate RMSE by using the same GCPs which were used for computing the warping. With 3 GCPs and 1st order polynomial transform the RMSE will be zero, as well as always with thin plate spline transform. The result does sometimes reveal bad GCPs. For reliable results measure new independent check points.

Comment: Ok, but how do I calculate the RMSE then? I thought the georeferenced GCP's would deviate from the original ones before warping. I'm using 2nd or 1st order polynomial depending on the amount of GCP's given.

Comment: When people are doin quality checks before paying to orthophoto contractors they use independent checkpoints which are collected with better accuracy than what is the demand for the end product. There are lots of litterature about the methods, first to meet the eye was http://www.asprs.org/a/publications/pers/2001journal/february/2001_feb_199-205.pdf.

Comment: But perhaps you want to test the model and your GCPs? Then play a bit with QGIS georeferencer http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_georeferencer.html. It tests the selected warping method with your GCPs and shows the residuals and RMSE even before running the actual warping.

Comment: Yeah the behaviour in QGIS' georeferencer is exactly what I'm trying to replicate. I just can't figure out how they do that. It's also based on GDAL, so it must be possible...

Comment: @user30184 -- i suggest you compile your comments into an answer